# Is there a way to integrate a better discussions solution with Rally?

Tags: rally

The discussion feature of Rally is very limited.  It does not support attachments or discussion threads.  These are required for my teams.  So is there a solution that integrates a better discussion solution with Rally?  If not, what would it take to find a third party dicussion/forum solution and integrate it into Rally, in such a way as to have the information displayed as part of the correct user story/defect/task and be able to support attachments and discussion threads?

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan,

At the moment, it will likely be hard to incorporate 3rd party discussion functionality into the Rally UI. We are working towards a more configurable and extensible UI with more accessible discussions. I see that you also posted this request on our ideas.rallydev.com site which will help us prioritize increasing the visibility and functionality of discussions.

Mark